# How can I shorten List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>?

Tags: c#, list, types, collections, generics

I want to store an list of key value pair lists in a lightweight structure. This seems too cumbersome. What's better? Does List<Dictionary<string, string>> add much a overhead? What other options are available?

Comment: What are you optimizing for? How is the structure going to be used? The title sounds like you're optimizing for the number of characters in your type declaration ;)

Comment: Yep, I just want to make it less cumbersome to look at :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider using aliasing for shorthand:

```
namespace Application
{
    using MyList = List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>;

    public class Sample
    {
        void Foo()
        {
            var list = new MyList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about that, but this helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Both `List` and `Dictionary` are pretty efficient, so I wouldn't think twice about using them. (Unless you're going to be storing a gazillion dictionaries in your list, but that's not very common.)

If you think that `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` is too much to type, you can say in your preamble

```
using LoDSS = System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>;
```

Note that this is just an alias no subclassing needed.

Comment: Apparently, this isn't completely correct, aliases can't stack on aliases so you have to using the following code instead:
using LoDSS = System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>;

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary< string, string> and List< KeyValuePair< string, string>> could both be fine, depending on what data you wanted to pass around.  Also, if you are going to use the same long type all over the place you could define the type somewhere else for a shorthand.  Something like this:

```
public class MyShorthand : List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> { }
```

Or you can use a using statement to define a type alias like this:

```
using MyShorthand = System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>>>;
```

Comment: The recommended way to alias types is the following: `using MyShorthand = List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>;`

Comment: @Noldorin: Especially since that avoids the problem of `sealed` types - not a problem in this case, but...

Comment: I didn't know you could add in type aliases with a using statement, thanks!

Comment: @person-b: Indeed. You're not really adding functionality, so there's no functional reason to inherit anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the values by the key, use dictionary, that is what is meant for. To reduce the overhead of the dictionaries, try and give them an initial capacity.

Alternatively (if both lists are rather small), you could implement a custom hashing object, something like this (except prettier):

```
public class MyDictionary
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> values;

    public MyDictionary()
    {
        values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public void Add(int index, string key, string value)
    {
        int hash = ((0xFFFF) & index) * (0xFFFF) + (0xFFFF) & key.GetHashCode();
        values.Add(hash, value);
    }
    public string Get(int index, string key)
    {
        int hash = ((0xFFFF) & index) * (0xFFFF) + (0xFFFF) & key.GetHashCode();
        return values[hash];
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting... too much for my needs though.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity I would wrap your `KeyValuePair<string, string>` into something shorter, e.g. `StringPair` and also define a shorthand for a list of `StringPair`. This will shorten your syntax and help readability IMHO.

```
public class StringPair : KeyValuePair<string, string> { }

public class StringPairList : List<stringPair> { }

..


var jaggedList = new List<StringPairList>();
```

Comment: KeyValuePair is a sealed class.. you can't derive from it.